# Using rel=canonical for subsection of pages

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have a page and I am kind of split between having a big page with lots of related contents or split into smaller pages. Creating smaller pages will result in thin content which is not liked well by Google.

So I was thinking if I can use `rel=canonical` to solve this problem to give a better user experience as they would see most of the information in one place.

For example if my page is about

> **All inclusive resorts in Cancun**
>
> Some text goes here about Cancun. The all inclusive resort would include drinks and food bla blah …
>
> "Top 30 All inclusive destinations in Cancun"
>
> List of 10 resorts with pagination
>
> Next                  Previous

Next comes a subsection

> **Cheapest all inclusive resorts**
>
> List of 10 resorts

Now this is the part "Cheapest all inclusive resorts" which I am not sure. I would have multiple sections like this in page.

Should I just include the link "Cheapest all inclusive resorts"?
Or show list of 5 resorts  with `rel=canonical` pointing to `http://mydomain-cheapest-all-inclusive-cancun-resorts`?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in different ways:

- Dedicate a page to `Cheapest all inclusive resorts` and differentiate content from the "parent" page. So, modify your copy (concentrate on the "cheapest" aspect instead of generic descriptions), use different images, etc. In that way, you don't need to point canonical to anywhere because you have different and specialized content. Put it in a subfolder like for example `resorts\cancun\cheapest`. Then just link that resource from the parent page. Best solution.
- If you want your content to be just a general topic about "resorts in cancun" because you see there's little competition and you can reach more people easily, simply follow pagination rules using `rel=next` and `rel=prev` (or use a `view=all` page). So, `cheapest all inclusive resorts` would be a page like any other of a bigger topic, or simply a section of a big page.

Comment: Really neat. The problem is list of resorts if sorted by price, will be same. So same list at two different places. I can have different description on page but not sure what to do about the list

Comment: For sorting purposes, use url parameters of your cms like ?sort=price. Then just set a canonical page to the url without the parameters.